# How to exclude helper projects with "Test" in their name from unit testing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

We have a utility project named `Foo.Testing.Common` with helper classes for our real test projects, named things like `Foo.Tests.Unit` and `Foo.Tests.Integration`. The Common project doesn't have tests, just base classes, utility methods and the like. It references XUnit so I can use `Xunit.Abstractions`.

How can we avoid seeing errors like the one below when we run all tests, either via .net command line or VS Test Explorer? The below error appears in VS Test Output during test discovery, for example.

```
No test is available in C:\Foo.Testing.Common\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Foo.Testing.Common.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException...
```

I assume the test process is matching on *test* to find test projects and then throws an error if one of those projects has no tests. Or maybe it's looking for projects that reference any xunit packages?

We could just rename the project, but is there a different way? Would like to avoid passing a list of specific test projects to the command line just to avoid the "no tests found" warnings. That is, `dotnet test` should just work.

Update: I've also tried referencing just `xunit.abstractions` and `xunit.extensibility.core` rather than the main `xunit` package, but the Common project still gets recognized as a test project.

Also tried setting `IsTestProject` to false in the project properties.

Answer (score 6):

In order to skip `Foo.Testing.Common` you can set `IsTestProject` property to false in Foo.Testing.Common.csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsTestProject>false</IsTestProject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting this error in test discovery output: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Unable to find C:\Foo\Foo.Testing.Common\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\testhost.dll. Please publish your test project and retry.` I tried a rebuild and restarted VS too.

Comment: What version of SDK do you use? Can you share the csproj file?

Comment: We're also getting this issue and `IsTestProject` `false` does not work. I think we're using 6.0.200 or 6.0.402

Comment: The issue on our end was that we have a custom `Directory.Build.targets` which sets `IsTestProject` `true` for projects that has a `Test` in its name